# apex:inputtextarea not setting value on the controller variable

Tags: apex, long-text-area

I'm having a problem with some apex:inputtextarea I have in my page. It's very similar to the situation described on this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/apexinputtext-value-not-setting-on-the-controller-variable); the thing is that I'm not doing any of the things that could cause this according to the post's answer. Or al least I don't think i am. I do have a little script function to validate if the fields are empty, that is fired when I click Save.

I've tried changing it to apex:inputText, apex:inputField; I even created a inner object in my controller to be used as a "bridge" between what's written in the page and what goes to the actual object that is saved. And my form is submitting just the variables are coming of null.

vf page:

```
<div class="title-form text-bold">Title:</div>
<apex:inputtextarea id="msg1" value="{!msg.title}" rows="2" cols="100"/>
```

controller:

```
public class Controller {

   public class MessageObject {
      public String title { get; set; } 
   }    
   public MessageObject msg { get; set; }

   (...)

   public PageReference saveChanges() {
      obj.Message_title__c = msg.title;
      update obj;
   }
}
```

Could someone point me to the light... or suggest a workaround for this.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

ECLF

Comment: I have faced this before when I had a command button with the immediate attribute set to true.

Comment: Are you instantiating msg anywhere? `msg = new MessageObject();` ?

Comment: E-bacho is right, you never instantiate msg, which is why it is null

Comment: @Richard N -- no immediate=true in my button... and i've checked several times.

Comment: @e-bacho 2.0 -- yes I am instanciating the object in the constructor... I just didn't post it here with the code. I have this custom object and on the page I can do 1 of 2 things: create (to insert a new record of this obj) and save (to update the current record of this obj). I have a bunch of other fields of this object that can be updated, such as dates, picklist, etc., even the field Name on the object (which is an inputtext) and all of them are updating just fine when I save. They are separeted by sections (but same form) on the page. Could it be it?
Thanks for all the replys.

Comment: Check the field level security of this field and make sure it's visible for the profile.

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue. I ran into a similar issue where I had an apex:InputText and apex:CommandLink. Due to formatting I moved them to separate div and therefore separate Apex:form elements and this was the problem for me. Both of them had to be under the same Apex:form.

Comment: Yes I checked fls and it's all good with that. I'm also sure that they are under the very same apex:form... I'm really running out of options and ideas here, I've tried using apex:inputtext, textarea, input... instead of using apex:inputtextarea and I'm getting nowhere. The value is simply not setting in controller... 
Thank you all for the responses!