# actionFunction behavior differ for inputCheckbox and inputText

Tags: apex, actionfunction, inputtext, onchange

Have some inputText fields and I'm doing some calculations with the values of these(inputFields are inside a pageblocktable, having wrapper items).

VF :

```
<apex:actionFunction name="calculateTotals" action="{!calculateTotals}" rerender="pnlSummary,errorMessagesinvoicePage"/>
<apex:inputText onchange="calculateTotals()" value="{!item.quantity}" ></apex:inputText>
```

Controller :

```
public void calculateTotals(){
        strInvoicePageErrorMessages = '';
        if(this.invoice != null){
            Double total, gst, subTotal = 0;
            for(InvoiceItemWrapper wrapper : invoiceItemWrapperList){
                try{
                    System.debug('cost:'+wrapper.itemCost + ' : quantity:'+wrapper.quantity);
                    subTotal += (wrapper.itemCost * wrapper.quantity);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('ERROR ' + e.getMessage() + ' : ' + e.getTypeName() );
                    if(e.getTypeName().contains('MathException') || e.getTypeName().contains('NullPointerException')){
                        strInvoicePageErrorMessages = 'Invalid values for quantity or item cost';
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is `actionFunction` getting fired for `onchange` event but it's not binding the values for wrapper items;they have their first load values. Ok I'll try an alternative if this is what you can expect from JavaScript-Apex combination.
But for a `inputCheckBox` it's binding the value correctly. Why is that?

```
<apex:actionFunction name="toggleSelectSchedules" action="{!toggleSelectAllSchedules}" rerender="pnlSearchResult" >
          </apex:actionFunction>
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="selectAll" value="{!selectAllSchedules}" onchange="toggleSelectSchedules();" id="ckbCheckAll" />
```

`selectAllSchedules` is binding correctly in the controller.

What I'm guessing is component we are triggering the event should have unique id. But it needs a dynamic id generation inside a pageblocktable

EDIT : 
No `immediate=true`, `actionRegion` or required field missing etc. It's just not assigning the user input value for inputText at the controller wrapper instance. The same working when using `commandButton`

Comment: Do you get the same result if you make the `calculateTotals` actionFunction rerender `pnlSearchResult`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apex:InputText value not setting on the controller variable](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/apexinputtext-value-not-setting-on-the-controller-variable)

Comment: It's not about a rerendering issue @Rob, it simply not assigning values for controller wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with an alternative. Added `actionSupport` for `inputText` fields to be fired in the `onchange` event. Working as expected.

```
<apex:inputText id="quantity" value="{!item.quantity}" >
      <apex:actionSupport action="{!calculateTotals}" rerender="pnlSummary" event="onchange"/>       
</apex:inputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason for this behaviour can be

1. Areas of the page are being rerendered, but not a page messages
   component, and an required field is missing or a validation rule is
   failing. In this scenario the error will be swallowed and the page
   will remain unchanged.
2. The form submission is using an action region, which excludes the
   input from the server side processing.
3. The form submission component (e.g. commandbutton, actionfunction)
   has the immediate attribute set to true. This will bypass validation
   rules but also discard any input from the user.

You can refer this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/apexinputtext-value-not-setting-on-the-controller-variable) in SFSE

Comment: I updated the question, it's not about not rerendering correctly.but about not assigning the updated UI values at the controller